# Crystal Reports for VS2015 Showing only a list of colors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I am running *Visual Studio 2015 Community* with *Crystal Reports for Visual Studio* installed. When I add fields and preview my report, it shows a list of colors instead of the data in my table.

I verified the data source is correct. Thinking that this was a registration/purchasing issue, I clicked "Register..." in the "Crystal Reports" menu - and it took me to the SAP homepage, saying the page I requested does not exist. Apparently it can't be registered, but it doesn't want to show my data either.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you show preview

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out on my own.  I hadn't previously downloaded MySQL ODBC Connector (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).  Once I did that, I then chose ODBC as a datasource instead of using MySQL Database at 'localhost' as the source.  Once I reconnected the report to the ODBC data source, everything appeared as it should.